# Is it necessary to specify default=django.utils.timezone.now while creating automatic primary key field for Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I created model

```
Class Team(models.Model):
    team = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

After it i saved some objects from this model and decided to change manually created primary key field to auto primary key field. I changed previously created model to

```
Class Team(models.Model):
    team = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

After it i run `python manage.py makemigrations` Django promted that i need specify **default=django.utils.timezone.now** here is my question what reason to specify this field with **django.utils.timezone.now** Why i can create primary key field without specifying it? What if i delete default=django.utils.timezone.now from migrations file and will migrate it ?

Comment: You have removed `primary_key=True`, so Django wants to create a new primary key field `id`. It is prompting you to provide a default for the new field, and gives `default=django.utils.timezone.now` as a possibility. It isn't telling you you have to use `default=django.utils.timezone.now`.

Comment: Adding the new `id` column is complicated because you need to set unique ids for all the existing rows. If your project is still under development you may find it easier to a) drop the database and exisiting data, delete the migrations, then create new migrations, or b) remove the `Team` model and create a migration to drop the table, then add the model back and create another migration to create the table.

Comment: @Alasdair i did as in your 'b' option. But i interested why i should specify it

Comment: Whenever a Django migration adds a field with `null=False` you need to specify a default (in the migration or when you run migrate), otherwise the `NOT NULL` constraint will fail. Removing `primary_key=True` causes Django to add an `id` field which doesn't allow nulls, so you need to specify the default. As far as I know, Django isn't smart enough to add the primary key field, set unique ids for each row then add the unique and not null constraints to the new column.